# Как переустановить Ubuntu и не потерять данные на RAID 1 (mdadm)?

Tags: linux, массивы, ubuntu, debian, raid

Добрый день, Имеется программный raid1, необходимо переустановить линукс. Не будут ли форматированы диски при создании нового рейда?

Answer (score 3):

Бекап важный файлов никогда не мешает.

Загрузитесь с LiveCD/LiveUSB. Если Файловая система видна корректно, то значит все получится. Если у Вас разбито правильно (то есть `/home` и `/` (корень) лежат в отдельных разделах), то просто отформатируйте корень и устанавливайте систему (при этом лучше поискать там возвожность расширенной установки).

Если же система поставленна по виндовому (то есть, все в один раздел), то загрузившись с лайва, поудаляйте все, кроме `/home` и устанавливайте систему, при этом, не забудьте снять галочки "форматировать раздел".

Answer (score 1):

Я надеюсь, что ОС установлена на отдельном жестком диске, не имеющем отношения к массиву. Этот диск можно отформатировать и поставить новую ОС.

После переустановки ОС запустите поиск созданных ранее массивов:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Так можно посмотреть текущее состояние массива:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Создайте конфиг-файл для массива:

```
mdadm --detail --scan --verbose > /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Создайте точку монтирования для массива:

```
mkdir /home/myRAID
```

Для того, чтобы массив загружался при каждой загрузке ОС, Добавим строчку в /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/md0 /home/myRAID ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Эта запись подразумевает, что адрес устройства вашего массива /dev/md0 (уточните это, сделайте ls /dev/md*); а так же, что у вас файловая система ext4. Если у вас другая, впишите другое соответствующее значение (например, ext3, NTFS, итд.) Далее даны стандартные параметры, подробне можно прочитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).

Монтируем массив:

```
mount -a
```

Эта команда монтирует всё, что ещё не примонтировано в системе, но указано в /etc/fstab.

p.s. 
так же, посмотреть на текущее состояние массива можно командой:

```
mdadm -D /dev/md0
```

Перед переустановкой ОС убедитесь, что с вашим массивом всё в порядке.